# Inserting HTML data from another website into a specific element (bootstrap) with ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, dom, jsonp

I need to get the text that is inside of a span from another website into my main website. I get the data that I want if I use a console log so the code is correct. Whowever I cannot insert it in my HTML, I want to insert the data found in the span in

`"$('.div-contandor .contador-numeros.col-md-8 span')"`

```
             $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://crossorigin.me/http://url',
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: 'html',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    success: function(data){

                        console.log( $(data).find('span').text() );
                        // this works and it gives me the number I want to insert in my own span

                         //This does not work and the html looks blank.
                        $('.div-contandor .contador-numeros.col-md-8 span').html( $(data).find('span').text() );

                    }
                });
```

Comment: If the `console.log` shows your correct data, but the `html()` call doesn't, then your selector is not matching any elements. Try logging this to the console: `$('.div-contandor .contador-numeros.col-md-8 span').length`

Comment: That made me realize that I was writting ".div-contandor" instead of "div-contador", wow.

Comment: It's always the simplest things you forget to check for :)